# get all categories listing from database

Tags: php

Main purpose is to get all categories listing from database by passing variables to url and show it to the main page.here i have omitted some code bt i tried to clarify.

1.can I exclude encodeHtml() method, too difficult for me to understand

2.i am not getting specially this part of code and having my head for 4 days

```
foreach($cats as $cat) {
echo "<li><a href=\"/?page=catalogue&category=".$cat['id']."\"";//here id is 'category id' from database. this full line will echo what?
 echo Helper::getActive(array('category' => $cat['id']));//it will output what ?
    echo ">";
  echo Helper::encodeHtml($cat['name']);//as from ur answer can we omit encodeHTML() method and use htmlspecialchars($cat['name']);  instead ? 
  echo "</a>
```

3.any easier solution will be more appreciated

in our database we have 'id' and 'name' of catagory listing

### please check below for reference

```
/*below is the code in header section of template */
        <?php
        $objCatalogue = new Catalogue();// creating object of Catalogue class
        $cats = $objCatalogue->getCategories(); // this gets all categories from database
        <h2>Categories</h2>
                        <?php 
                            foreach($cats as $cat) {
                                echo "<li><a href=\"/?page=catalogue&amp;category=".$cat['id']."\"";
                                echo Helper::getActive(array('category' => $cat['id']));
                                echo ">";
                                echo Helper::encodeHtml($cat['name']);
                                echo "</a></li>";
                            }
                        ?>
    /*below is the helper class which is Helper.php */
        public static function getActive($page = null) {
                if(!empty($page)) {
                    if(is_array($page)) {
                        $error = array();
                        foreach($page as $key => $value) {
                            if(Url::getParam($key) != $value) //getParam takes name of the parameter and returns us the value by $_GET
{
                                array_push($error, $key);
                            }
                        }
                        return empty($error) ? " class=\"act\"" : null;
                    }
                }
//CHECK THIS LINE BROTHER
                return $page == Url::currentPage() ? " class=\"act\"" : null;// url::currentPage returns the current page but what is 'class =act '  :(
            }
            public static function encodeHTML($string, $case = 2) {
                switch($case) {
                    case 1:
                    return htmlentities($string, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);
                    break;          
                    case 2:
                    $pattern = '<([a-zA-Z0-9\.\, "\'_\/\-\+~=;:\(\)?&#%![\]@]+)>';
                    // put text only, devided with html tags into array
                    $textMatches = preg_split('/' . $pattern . '/', $string);
                    // array for sanitised output
                    $textSanitised = array();           
                    foreach($textMatches as $key => $value) {
                        $textSanitised[$key] = htmlentities(html_entity_decode($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                    }           
                    foreach($textMatches as $key => $value) {
                        $string = str_replace($value, $textSanitised[$key], $string);
                    }           
                    return $string;         
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: check the 2 no. question bro.... can u make me understand that code

Comment: Which specific part of it do you not understand? The functions themselves? Or the way they are called? Or something else?

Comment: Alright well I guess I could give an answer, check the one posted below though, if it does not help you I'll try to come up with one.

Comment: ok bro i m trying to understand the answer as all those methods are new to me.. u may give ur simplified answer too bro :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in your URL (`/?page=catalogue&amp;category=`) you don't need to put `&amp;`, as this is an HTML entity for actually displaying an ampersand in a web page. Just use `/?page=catalogue&category=`.

Secondly, you can use [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to prepare strings for sending in the URL, and [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) on the other end.

In answer to your first point you just need to make sure that ANYTHING from the user (whether via `$_POST` or `$_GET`) is sanitized, prior to being used in code, output to a web page, or used in database queries. Use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) for cleaning before outputting to a web page, and prepared statements prior to entering user input into a query.

In answer to your second point please read the documentation in the links I have provided above. Just reading the documentation on `htmlspecialchars()` will help you a lot.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hey brother your answer helped me a lot but few confusion though. i have edited no. 2 question and pointed my problems beside codes.it will be extremely helpful if u make it clear

Answer (score 0):

Alright then.

```
                    <?php 
                        foreach($cats as $cat) {
                            echo "<li><a href=\"/?page=catalogue&amp;category=".$cat['id']."\"";
                            echo Helper::getActive(array('category' => $cat['id']));
                            echo ">";
                            echo Helper::encodeHtml($cat['name']);
                            echo "</a></li>";
                        }
                    ?>
```

Im just going to kindof skim through it, because honestly if you really want to learn all this you should probably google the shit out of every piece of code you don't understand, it's the way we all learn things.

- < ?php announces some php script to follow. And as you can see, there does follow some php code after.
- foreach is a way of getting each element from an array or list and doing something to that element.
- echo sends whatever string comes after it to the page, or whatever is listening to its output. In this case, it looks like the echo's are printing some `<li>` list item with an `<a>` anchor in it.
- Helper::getActive(): Helper is some class that is defined somewhere, :: is syntax for calling a static function that belongs to the class (Helper in this case). getActive is the function name.
- array('category' => $cat['id'] is a piece of code that creates an array with 1 element in it, being one with key 'category' and a value of whatever is in $cat['id'].

By looking at getActive: it looks like it's a function that checks the url for some value so it can determine which page to display. It also checks if the url contains errors.

By lookingat encodeHtml(): it looks like it's a function that makes sure that whatever text you're trying to put on the screen, isn't something that could cause harm. In some situations, people will try to make your server print javascript that could harm the user (by sending personal data to somewhere). The encodeHtml() will ensure that no such thing can be done by stripping certain characters from the text you're about to send to the page.

USE GOOGLE.

Comment: wow very simple answer bt i have studied and finally sorted out few problems. i have edited question 2 if u please see it would be great help to me